# Validate unique text using Express Validator & Mongoose

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, express-validator

I have a mongodb collections named "`articles`"

I have configured below rules for validating "`title`" field of article while **Updating** the record.

```
validator.body('title').custom( (value, {req}) => {
    console.log(value, req.params.id)
    return Article.find({ title:value, _id:{ $ne: req.params.id } })
      .then( article => {
      if (article) {
        return Promise.reject('Title already in use');
      }
    })
  })
```

So basically it should check if "title" should not exists in the collection and it should not be the same ID as the one I am updating.

The line `console.log(value, req.params.id)` is printing proper Title and ID but the validation is always saying "Title already in use". Even though I use entirely different title that is not used at all.

Any idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use findOne query for better performance and check data is null like as bellow.

```
validator.body('title').custom( (value, {req}) => {
    console.log(value, req.params.id)
    return Article.findOne({ title:value, _id:{ $ne: req.params.id } })
      .then( article => {
      if (article !== null) {
        return Promise.reject('Title already in use');
      }
    })
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

Stupid mistake,

the

```
if (article) {
```

is supposed to be

```
if (article.length) {
```

And it worked fine.